# How to implement HDR setting in react native camera?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) in my app. This is provide image capture and another some settings on camera preview like flash settings, white balance mode etc. But, I will not find any documents about HDR setting.

Can anyone know how to implement HDR setting.

Here is the some code that I have written to display camera preview in my app.

```js
<RNCamera style={{flex:1, flexGrow:1}}
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          type={this.state.cameraType}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          flashMode={this.state.flashMode}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

React-native-camera does not have the ability to take pictures in HDR mode.